# How to delete check box from Android Gridview

Tags: android

I'm implementing to delete check box with images in Android grid-view.I have done to delete checked images but check box appear as it is .How to remove check-boxes also from grid.Can some one help me to resolve this issues for check box.
This is my getView() methid in Adapter class

*

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
           ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_post_grid_item_layout, parent , false);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName.get(position));
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
                    int pos = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    if (!buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        picsName.remove((String) fileName.get(pos));
                    } else if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        if (!picsName.contains((String) fileName.get(pos))) {
                            picsName.add((String) fileName.get(pos));
                        }
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
```

This delete button in Activity class

```
 imgDeleteImagesFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int len = selectedItems.size() - 1;
                    for (int i = len; i > 1; i--)
                    {
                        fileName.remove(i);
                        fileName.remove((Integer) vh.checkbox.getTag(i));
                        if(checks.get(i)==1){
                            checks.remove(i);
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    gridView.clearChoices();
                }
            });
```

This is row xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you upload your row xml as well? Also upload a screenshot with your issue...

Comment: @ user320676 : Hi thanks to reply .I editrd my post and also upload a screenshot with issue.

Comment: put your setOnCheckedChangeListener code inside                                             if (convertView == null){                                                                                         convertView.setTag(holder);                                                                                                        } and try

Comment: but one point is if you deleted two images then your third image should be on first position. But non deleted image is still on third position it means your adapter list is still having size == 3.

Comment: Yes , Actually . That's why i want to know how to remove also check-box with image .

Comment: @user320676 : I tried whatever you suggest , but not work . Still check box is appear as it is.

Comment: are you using arraylist in your adapter? How u r setting your adapter size? If you are using arraylist then check the list size after deletion.

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand what you saying .

Comment: ArrayList<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>(); this the arraylist which i have used . In that array-list stored the images from camera and gallery .

Comment: try changing your for loop from for (int i = len; i > 1; i--) to for (int i = selectedItems.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) in your onClick method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97194/discussion-between-user320676-and-p-ld).

Comment: No, Still same issue check box is unchecked only ,but after deletion third images is not set at first position.

Comment: I think your for-loop logic is not correct. Check your logic. You are calling fileName.remove two times and also reducing the value of i inside your loop which is not correct.

Comment: for (int i = selectedItems.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) means you saying  this is wrong for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the selectedPic array to store the images that is selected on Adapter

```
private ArrayList<Integer> selectedPic = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Create this methods to track the selected the checkbox poisitions on Adapter Class

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getSelectedChecckedImages() {
        return selectedPic;
    }

    public void clearSelectedCheckedImages() {
        selectedPic.clear();
    }
```

getView of the adapter Class

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    layout = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_post_grid_item_layout, parent, false);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mConext.getResources(), data.get(position));
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    holder.text.setText("" + position);
    holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(selectedPic.contains(data.get(position)));
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int pos = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            if (!buttonView.isChecked()) {
                selectedPic.remove(data.get(pos));
            } else if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                if (!selectedPic.contains(data.get(pos))) {
                    selectedPic.add(data.get(pos));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Delete button event in your activity

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (Integer obj : adapter.getSelectedChecckedImages()) {
            data.remove(obj);
        }
        adapter.clearSelectedCheckedImages();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

let me know if you still have any issues i will help

Comment: hi , here is some issue at my side

Comment: ArrayList<String> data= new ArrayList<String>();   and  private ArrayList<Integer> selectedPic = new ArrayList<Integer>(); selectedPic.add(data.get(pos));  The issue is add (java.lang.Integer) in ArrayList can not be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: Can i use ArrayList<String> selectedPic = new ArrayList<String>(); instead of ArrayList<Integer> selectedPic = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: Or can i use like this =    holder.checkbox.setChecked(selectedPic.contains(Integer.parseInt(fileName.get(position))));
 selectedPic.add(Integer.parseInt(fileName.get(pos))); It is posible to delete

Comment: @p.ld yes you can but need to map the object  with data array

Comment: @p.ld So what you need to do is You have to save the same object in selectedPic arraylist that we have in the data arraylist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97369/discussion-between-p-ld-and-sandy).

Comment: Hi , Are you there ?

Comment: Please I want your help .

Comment: I'm trying to upload data on server last 3 days but my data is not uploaded on server.I'm using  HttpPost method , but always getting status false even my all parameter is  right .And tried all the way of post the data on server but still not upload my data on server .

Comment: hello , are you busy ?

Comment: Yes i had some work i will contact you when i will be free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101746/discussion-between-p-ld-and-sandy).